# Magento 2 : Get list of products for which backorder is enabled

Tags: magento2, backorder

How to get list of products for which backorder is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject this below class in your construct :

```
protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    .....
) {
    .....
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    .....
}
```

Now you can use this below code for fetch collection based on backorders.

```
$productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->joinField(
    'backorders',
    'cataloginventory_stock_item',
    'backorders',
    'product_id = entity_id',
)->joinTable(
    'cataloginventory_stock_item',
    'product_id = entity_id',
    ['']
)
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED
)->load();
```

For backorder enabled only, add more filter :

```
->addAttributeToFilter(
        'backorders',
        1
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohan. It worked.